# Where to begin with sockets in a simple multiplayer JAVA game

Tags: java, sockets, client-side, serversocket

I've have recently been exploring my own idea to make a little multiplayer game that a couple of my friends could play just for the fun of it. I know all the basics, a little more to java, i would consider myself an intermediate at java.

Recently I've been learning on how to load sprites, double buffering, key listeners, mouse listeners, etc for making a little side scroller 2d gun game. And I have a good understand of these categories, but now I've come to the part where I need to learn about sockets and such to be able to get this game online.

I've seen a little tutorial on where a server and client were made, and when the client was opened would send a message (string) to the server, for example "Orange" and the server could understand that, and print it out. I can understand the code by looking at it (if asked to reconstruct that from my own knowledge (slash memory) would be unable to, because I don't know sockets).

Now to my main question, how can I start to go about doing something like this, when doing this, how to a registrated the movement,for example, from one client to the server which would then appear on all clients connected and in the game, as well with bullets, collision events, enemies, etc. I cant seem to find any good help out there that really shows you how to do this, by creating a socket, doing all the basic connection stuff (which i dont know) and then updating the game state if i can call it that.

So in all, how can I basically take a game with has a ground, two players (represented by sprites) some enemies (AI) and bullets able to kill the enemies, and the ability for the enemies to fire back and kill the players (Users) and make a server and client out of it? Oh and one more thing, I'd like to have the ability for the player to choose a name as well, and the name lets say would float above the players character in the game... And if is even possible to have a little built in chat function, but i might be getting to advanced on that one.

If someone can just at least point me in the right direction, or explain the basics around all this, then that would be great! Thanks!

-Dan

I apologize if I through a lot out there, I just want to explain what im looking to be able to do

Comment: Ok, you thought and that's good. But now, try something and come back here if you need help on code. There are plenty of tutorials about sockets on the web.

Comment: Start with the [Java Tutorial on Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).

Comment: Wow, take a breath (use some paragraphs)!

Answer (score 1):

What you will need is a multithreaded server, that listenes for incomming data from the players, and then update accordingly. The client also needs to be threaded and listen for incomming data from the server so it can update other players movement etc. So start by reading up on sockets and threads. You want the server to create one thread for each client that is connected.

Then make a first try by sending messages to a server, which echos back the same messages to the client. This will require that you use threads and sockets and is a good way to start.

You will be using the same tequniqe for your game later (clients send their movement to the server, and the server echos the movement to all the other clients so they can update the changes locally) OR, the clients send movements to the server, the server updates the movements locally. This will require that the clients get x and y cordinates of all the objects stored on the server. This might be better in case of lag (never programmed a game so not sure which approach will be best).

So, you will have infinite loops on both the server and the clients that each iteration gets/sends x and y axis of each object and use that to repaint/handle hits and so on. Which logic lies in which loop will depend on the design you choose.